# Rows lock order and deadlock risk using SELECT FOR UPDATE with JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, deadlock, select-for-update

Consider the following transaction:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
WHERE A.id = 123
ORDER BY A.id, B.id
FOR UPDATE;

-- more ops...

COMMIT;
```

I'm using the `ORDER BY` clause just to ensure that rows are locked in a consistent way so that, if multiple concurrent connections execute the same transaction, a deadlock would not happen.

My questions are:

1. Am I using the `ORDER BY` clause in the right way (considering I'm doing a `JOIN`)?
2. In what exact order are the rows locked? **I'm triyng to lock all rows from table A before (in order by id) and then all rows from table B (again in order by id)** but I guess this is not the right way to go.

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75698590/deadlock-when-using-select-for-update-with-in-list) months ago, but `JOIN` clause was not used.

Answer (score 0):

The rows will be locked in the order that they are emitted by the `ORDER BY`. One consequence of that is that it will lock rows from both tables – one result row of the join will consist of a row from each of the tables.

Note that if the `id` columns receive concurrent updates, the result may have an ordering different from the one specified in `ORDER BY`, so rows could get locked in a different order than you intend. But then, primary keys should not get modified anyway.

Assuming that `id` is never updated, and you want to lock the rows in `a` first, you could use a temporary table:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP TABLE t ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id
FROM a
   JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE a.id = 123;

SELECT ...
FROM a
   JOIN t ON a.id = t.a_id
ORDER BY a.id
FOR NO KEY UPDATE;

SELECT ...
FROM b
   JOIN t ON b.id = t.b_id
ORDER BY b.id
FOR NO KEY UPDATE;

/* other processing */

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, let me check if I got you: if table A contains rows with A.id 1,2,3 and B contain rows with B.id 4,5,6 (respectively related to 1,2,3) lock order is A.id=1, B.id=4,A.id=2, B.id=5,A.id=3, B.id=6 ? If so, it's a problem in my domain. I would like to lock all rows from A followed by all rows from B. Moreover, both "groups" should be locked in order (by their id, that is a PRIMARY KEY) to avoid deadlock

Comment: Yes, you got that right. I have added an idea what you could do to achieve your goal.